# Are there any market data providers that provide a query language?

Tags: online-data-source, market-data

Like SQL, for example, but it doesn't have to be the same syntax. For example, I might want to query "which stocks on the NYSE had the greatest 1-hour price changes today?"

Comment: Bloomberg and Reuters would be very happy to provide you with the information, albeit for a fee.

Comment: Note: query language does not mean some excel functions and the like. It must be a language in which I can write sentences, for example SQL.

Comment: http://www.stockfetcher.com

Answer (score 3):

You can give YQL a try. I'm not sure it can do the query you want, but for example you can do:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("GOOG","AAPL","MSFT","YHOO") 
order by DaysValueChange
```

[(try it here)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22GOOG%22,%22AAPL%22,%22MSFT%22,%22YHOO%22%29%20order%20by%20DaysValueChange%20)

And this best thing about it - it's free.